# ModuleNotFoundError only occurs when starting app in Docker

Tags: python, django, linux, docker, docker-compose

I am currently experimenting with cookiecutters. I'm creating a template for Django, which is working. The next step is to add a docker container for it. For some reason i get following error when I run docker-compose up (or just start the django app manually from within the container):

```
app_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
app_1  |     self.run()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
app_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
app_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
app_1  |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
app_1  |     raise _exception[1]
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
app_1  |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
app_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
app_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_1  |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
app_1  |     module = import_module(entry)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
app_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
app_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
app_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
app_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'd'
```

When I run the django app manually, everything is working just fine.
I will also add my Dockerfile and my docker-compose.yaml:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    APP_ROOT=/var/app

# Install waitfor
ENV WAITFOR_VERSION="v2.1.1"
RUN set -x \
    && BUILD_PACKAGES=' \
        curl \
    ' \
    && RUNTIME_PACKAGES=' \
        gosu \
        netcat \
    ' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ${BUILD_PACKAGES} ${RUNTIME_PACKAGES} \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/wait-for -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eficode/wait-for/${WAITFOR_VERSION}/wait-for \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ${BUILD_PACKAGES} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt ${APP_ROOT}/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex \
    && BUILD_PACKAGES='\
        build-essential \
        git-core \
        liblzma-dev \
        graphviz-dev\
    ' \
    && RUNTIME_PACKAGES=' \
        postgresql-client \
        postgresql-contrib \
        graphviz \
        lzma \
    ' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ${BUILD_PACKAGES} ${RUNTIME_PACKAGES} \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r ${APP_ROOT}/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get remove -y ${BUILD_PACKAGES} \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    \
    && find /usr/local -depth \
        \( \
            \( -type f -a \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \) \
        \) -exec rm -rf '{}' +

# COPY docker-dev-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/default-entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/default-entrypoint.sh"]

COPY ./ ${APP_ROOT}

WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
```

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis:12-master
    container_name: "my_demo_app_db"
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dev
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_demo_app
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/app
      - /tmp:/tmp
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - docker.env
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Does anyone know where the error is coming from and/or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your Django configuration file ?

Comment: Apologies for the late respons, but I was able to fix the error. I was wrongly appending apps to the INSTALLED_APPS in the django settings ( was doing += 'app_name' instead of += ['app_name'] )

Comment: Not clear why the error only occured in the container, but it works now

Comment: Yeah that's what I guessed from the stacktrace. Glad you fixed the mistake !